Selecting contrasts in emmeans
So, I have this model of a dataset I've build with a lot of information and now I'm trying to compare some of the variables I have with some others, but not everything with everything as tukey does.
It's kind of tricky because I want to compare "Primer_olor" of the trials that have a + in its name with "Segundo_olor" of the trials that have  _ on its name.
Also the other way around, "Segundo_olor" of the trials that have a + in its name with "Primer_olor" of the trials that have _.
But the US between the trials that have a + and the others that have a _.
m1=lm(value~ trial+variable+trial:variable+order_trial, data = Datoslat_percent)

> m1[["xlevels"]][["trial"]]
 [1] "+1" "_1" "+2" "_2" "+3" "_3" "+4" "_4" "+5" "_5"
> m1[["xlevels"]][["variable"]]
[1] "Primer_olor"  "Segundo_olor" "US" 


# Calculate emmeans with custom pairwise comparisons

emmres = emmeans(m1, pairwise ~ trial *variable, type = "response")
plot(emmres, comparisons=T)

With this I get every possible comparison. How could I filter them to get those I want?
I've tried making a list with the names of the contrasts and using grepl to get thos names, a couple of functions but nothing really worked.
custom_comparisons <- list(
  c("+1 Primer_olor", "_1 Segundo_olor"),
  c("+2 Primer_olor", "_2 Segundo_olor"),
  c("+3 Primer_olor", "_3 Segundo_olor"),
  c("+4 Primer_olor", "_4 Segundo_olor"),
  c("+5 Primer_olor", "_5 Segundo_olor"),
  c("_1 Primer_olor", "+1 Segundo_olor"),
  c("_2 Primer_olor", "+2 Segundo_olor"),
  c("_3 Primer_olor", "+3 Segundo_olor"),
  c("_4 Primer_olor", "+4 Segundo_olor"),
  c("_5 Primer_olor", "+5 Segundo_olor"),
  c("+1 US", "_1 US"),
  c("+2 US", "_2 US"),
  c("+3 US", "_3 US"),
  c("+4 US", "_4 US"),
  c("+5 US", "_5 US")
)

extracted_contrasts <- list()

for (comp in custom_comparisons) {
  contrast_names <- paste(comp[1], "-", comp[2])
  
  try({
    matching_contrasts <- grep(contrast_names, names(emmres$contrasts), value = TRUE)

    extracted_contrasts[[contrast_names]] <- emmres$contrasts[matching_contrasts]
  }, silent = TRUE)  # Suppress errors
}

extracted_contrasts


contrasts look like this "(+5 US) - _5 US" but I also changed the () on the list and got nowhere
